# AngularJS - ng-switch within ng-repeat and slice

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-switch

I have a simple ng-repeat that loops through a JSON file with a list of financial deposits.

However, i am trying to slice the first 12 entries and perform a ng-switch on the value:

HTML:

```
<td ng-repeat="deposit in MyData.MyDeposits.slice(0, 12)" ng-switch="WHATGOESHERE?">
    <span ng-switch-when="0">U</span>
    <span ng-switch-when="1">D</span>
    <span ng-switch-when="2">2</span>
    <span ng-switch-when="3">3</span>
    <span ng-switch-when="4" class="icon-warning">3</span>
</td>
```

JS:

```
function EventController($scope) {
    $scope.MyData = {
        "Name" : "Mr White",
        "MyDeposits": [
                "0",
                "0",
                "0",
                "U",
                "1",
                "2",
                "4",
                "0",
                "D",
                " ",
                " ",
                " ",
                " ",
                " ",
                " ",
                " ",
                " ",
                " ",
                " ",
                " ",
                " ",
                " "
         ];
    }
};
```

The issue i am facing is what do i place in my `ng-switch="WHATGOESHERE?"`

---

Added plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/WtFWVYVvRKm1pN19qlX8?p=preview

Comment: Can you please add a plunker for your question ??

Comment: @ManishKr.shukla - plunker added in question.

Comment: @ByteBlocks - tried that, i get the following error: Error: [ngRepeat:dupes] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.8/ngRepeat/dupes?p0=deposit %20in%20MyData.MyDeposits.slice(0%2C%2012)&p1=string%3AU

Comment: `<td ng-repeat="deposit in MyData.MyDeposits.slice(0, 12) track by $index" ng-switch="deposit">`